# docker Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.160.2:33061

Tags: javascript, docker

Im trying to connect my API to a database which are both in a docker container using docker compose. On initial connect this error occurs: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.160.2:33061. What am i doing wrong?

docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
 dbdata:

services:
  nesta:
    build: .
    container_name: nesta
    depends_on:
      - mysqla
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - .env:/app/.env


  mysqla:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysqla
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
```

env file:

```
# APP
APP_ENV=dev
APP_URL=http://localhost

# JWT AUTH
JWT_SECRET_KEY=uAsBw6WxqD
JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME=3600

# DATABASE
DB_TYPE=mysql
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_HOST=mysqla
DB_PORT=33061
DB_DATABASE=test
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect to your mysql server, you should use mysql cli

`mysql -u root -h 192.168.160.2:33061 -proot`

Answer (score 0):

`DB_PORT=33061`

I'm assuming your `nesta` app is attempting to connect to `mysqla` at port 33061?

You need to use port `3306` from your `nesta` container to connect to `mysqla`.

With the port binding configuration -  `"33061:3306"`, you are binding container port 3306 to host port 33061. If you are connecting from the host machine, then you can use 33061. When you use `docker-compose`, a docker network is created and your container `nesta` and `mysqla` are joined to this network automatically. So from your `nesta` container, you should access the `mysqla` container port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I think the port 33061 in host is already in use.
if using linux chack:

```
ss -tuple
```